# How to write If statement in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, error-handling

I am writing if statement like that:

```
String value;
if(int.parse(value)) // I want to write a condition that if error appear while parsing 
// (like value contains some strings) then if statement run
```

It can be achieved by writing try/catch

```
try{ 
int.parse(value)
}
catch (e) {
// implement if statement
}
```

But I want to do this with if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try a different approach using `tryParse()` [method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/int/tryParse.html) and check whether the result is `null` then the parse failed.

```dart
if (int.tryParse(value)==null){ // execute failed parse code }
```